# Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.manage()" because "this.driver" is null

Tags: selenium

I have created two classes. One class am using for webdriver initialization and in another class am extending the properties of my first class so that I don't have to initialize my webdriver again and again and after that using that web driver object (from the first class) am trying to perform some actions. Now my chrome is initialized but further, it is performing no actions in it and it is showing Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.manage()" because "this.driver" is null.
Please refer my screenshots below:

[class 1][1]

[class 2][3]

[File ][2]

[3]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBOnJ.png`import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBOnJ.png%60import) java.io.IOException;

Class 1

``````
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    
    public class project1 extends project1classB {
        
    
        @Test
        public void basePageNavigation() throws IOException
        {
            
            driver = initializeDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/");
            
            
            
            
        }
    }`````

`


class 2

    ````import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    
    
    public class project1classB  {
        public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fil= new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\mimo\\eclipse-workspace\\Guru99Assignment\\src\\data.properties");
        prop.load(fil);
        String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
        if(browserName.equals("chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\mimo\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/");
            
            }
        else if(browserName.equals("firefox"))
        {
            
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;  
    }
    
    }````


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQnyn.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHOda.png
``````

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide your code, but from the error you received it's clear that you did not initialize the driver object instance.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I have attached the screenshots up there. Please click on Class 1 and Class 2, let me know if you are able to see them or not.

Comment: I see no parameter browserName passed there. I guess it should came from TestNG, but you don't shot it

Comment: I have also attached my file screenshot from where am taking BrowserName value. Please look into it.

Comment: Well, we have to debug there. The FileInputStream fil, the prop.load(fil), String Browsername...

Comment: What I think is there is no error in my second class as am able to open my chrome browser successfully from it but when it comes to calling the method from another class and using that driver object to further perform actions it is failing there. I have also used this keyword but nothing is helping.

Comment: Again, we have to debug it, but you don't provide ALL the relevant code. Moreover, you are providing pictures, not a code.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by myself what I was doing wrong here was initializing my Webdriver two times in my class 2 due to which it was giving this error.

Answer (score 0):

Issue sloved
I also had this kind of issue.

(1). Check whether excel sheets whether having null data.

(2). I added border to the whole column in excel and again checked with removing those borders and issue was solved.

(3). Excel column borders adding this issue BE CAREFUL WHEN ADDING BORDERS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9KsM.png)